Writing a large Polars LazyFrame as partitioned parquet
I need to write a large Polars LazyFrame with partitioning, after processing. I am running into memory issues.
Since Polars does not support sinking LazyFrames with partitioning, I am saving the LazyFrame without partitioning to disk with the sink_parquet method (which works fine), and then trying to scan the file with a Pyarrow dataset scanner, and write it with the Pyarrow write_dataset method:
import tempfile

from loguru import logger
import polars as pl
import pyarrow.dataset


raw_data = pl.scan_parquet("raw_data.parquet")
# write data processing, without collecting

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp_file:
    raw_data.sink_parquet(tmp_file.name)
    scanner = pyarrow.dataset.dataset(tmp_file.name).scanner()
    pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset(
        scanner, "/path/to/data/", format="parquet",
        partitioning=["date"],
        partitioning_flavor="hive",
        max_partitions=1826,  # 5 years in days
        file_visitor=lambda f: logger.info(f"Wrote {f.path}"),
        existing_data_behavior="delete_matching"
    )

I am getting OOM when Pyarrrow tries to write the dataset. Is there any way to optimize this?
Setting small values for row_group_size in the sink_parquet method and for batch_size in the scanner method didn't help.
I still have this problem with partitioning off in the write_dataset method.

Could you let me know if you solved this issue?

I've found specific settings that minimize memory pressure, with an additional step of processing. I'll post an answer.
